# fancybox jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

The link in concern is http://amijangla.com/view-projects/projects/projects/blogbeats.html

I have implemented the simple fancy box.But it does not seem to work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery a second time, after you have already included the fancybox plugin.
You should try to move all your included scripts down to the bottom of your html instead of splitting it up in your head and body.